# Flutter - Display just month in Datetime picker Timeline

Tags: flutter, datetime, datetimepicker, timeline

[image]

In my app, I am using the Datetime Picker Timeline view of DatePicker, but I want to display the name of the current month. Is there a way to display month name?

Comment: It has option to set day date and Month text style try editing those

Comment: add some code to get better help

Comment: okee, i will try, thank before.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you can only get the number. What I usually do is:

```
const List months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

You can then use the number given by DateTime as the index like:

```
months[(DateTime.now().month)-1]
```

-1 because index starts at 0 and month at 1.